# why the alert has no value?

Tags: javascript

```
<title>New Web Project</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var paras = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
            for (var i=0; i< paras.length; i++) {
            var title_text = paras[i].getAttribute("title");
            if (title_text != null) {
                alert(title_text);
                }
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>New Web Project Page</h1>
        <p title="test"> This is just a test</p>
    </body>
```

why the alert has no value? i feel it should popup the text `test`.

Comment: You're calling the JS before the DOM is complete.

Comment: If you are okay with jQuery then wrap it up in document.ready just check it out..

Comment: +1. While it's not a great question as far as the text itself, it provides the relevant info (code being used, explanation of what you expected and what you got instead, and what you want to know). @Ascension: What difference does that make? It has nothing to do with the question asked.

Comment: @KenWhite, it was just a suggestion for future use, not to answer the question. So put as comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because when the `script` is evaluated, `p` has **not** been loaded *yet*.

If you add the `script` right *after* `p`, when `p` is already rendered, it will show the `alert` as expected:

```
<p title="test"> This is just a test</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var paras = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  for (var i=0; i< paras.length; i++) {
    var title_text = paras[i].getAttribute("title");
    if (title_text != null) {
      alert(title_text);
    }
}
</script>
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b6hJF/)**.

Answer (score 2):

Because you initialize the script before html elements are rendered.

Move the script to bottom or wait for DOM. Like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>New Web Project</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
            var paras = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
            for (var i=0; i< paras.length; i++) {
            var title_text = paras[i].getAttribute("title");
            if (title_text != null) {
                alert(title_text);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>New Web Project Page</h1>
    <p title="test"> This is just a test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While you are correct about the OP calling *getElementsByTagName* before the document is complete, the first few lines of your code aren't doing anything useful. The second assignment to *window.onload* replaces the first, so if any previous function had been assigned, it isn't called.

Comment: The first line is for some versions of IE that don't know about window.onload, so I am  creating a function for that if it doesn't exist

Comment: The third line of the above means that whatever was previously assigned to `window.onload` will never be called. What versions of IE don't support window.onload? Certainly IE 6+ does, and I'd be very surprised if versions 5 or 4 didn't.